# Два двумерных ассоциативных массива. Первый создан на основе второго. Теперь из первого нужно добавить значения во второй

Tags: php, массивы

Есть А-массив (всегда 7 элементов):

```
Array
(
    [Понедельник, 19 Ноября] => Array
        (
            [0] => aaa
            [1] => bbb
            [2] => ccc
            и т.д
        )

    [Вторник, 20 Ноября] => 
            [0] => qqq
            [1] => iii  
            и т.д
)
```

На его основе сделал массив В (элементов может быть неизвестно сколько, но не больше 7):

```
Array
(
    [Понедельник, 19 Ноября] => Array
        (
            [-1] => kkk
        )

    [Среда, 21 Ноября] => Array
        (
            [-2] => yyy
            [-1] => hhh
        )

    [Пятница, 23 Ноября] => Array
        (
            [-1] => rrr
        )

)
```

Теперь что нужно сделать. Из массива В каждый день прибавить к дню следующему массива А. Например, из В-массива берем "Понедельник, 19 Ноября" и прибавляем ко "Вторнику, 20 Ноября" А-массива. "Среду, 21 Ноября" В-массива прибавляем к "Четвергу, 22 Ноября" А-массива и т.д. В результате должно получиться:

```
Array
    (
        [Понедельник, 19 Ноября] => Array
            (
                [0] => aaa
                [1] => bbb
                [2] => ccc
                и т.д
            )

        [Вторник, 20 Ноября] => 
                [-1] => kkk 
                [0] => qqq
                [1] => iii  
                и т.д

        [Среда, 21 Ноября] =>
        ...
        [Четверг, 22 Ноября] =>
                [-2] => yyy
                [-1] => hhh
                [0] => aaa
        [Пятница, 23 Ноября] =>
        ...
        [Суббота, 24 Ноября] =>
                [-1] => rrr
                [0] => aaa
                [2] => uuu
    )
```

Я уже второй день бьюсь, не получается ничего придумать. Прошу помощи у Вас! Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Странный пример у вас, ключи не совпадают, в итоге не понятно что должно получиться.

Comment: @Yaroslav Molchan, поэтому отрицательные ключи, чтоб потом при складывании значения не затирались

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю хранить ключ-дату в нормальном машиночитаемом формате, например date("U") и далее работать примерно так:

```
foreach($array_b as $date=>$arr){
    foreach($arr as $k=>$v){
        $array_a[strtotime($date."+1 days")][$k]=$v;
    }
}
```

Comment: это я парсил txt, там такие даты стоят...

Comment: @forever_young конвертируй даты, насколько я помню strtotime() с русскими датами не работает, загугли либу/скрипт/костыл для русских дат

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_result_array = array();
$ru_day_names = array('Понедельник','Вторник','Среда','Четверг','Пятница','Суббота','Воскресенье');
foreach($ru_day_names as $day){
        foreach($array_b as $k=>$v){
            if(stristr($k,$day)){
                $new_result_array[$k]=[$v];
                continue 2;
            }
        }
        foreach($array_a as $k=>$v){
            if(stristr($k,$day)){
                $new_result_array[$k]=[$v];
                break;
            }
        }

}
```

при необходимости (приоритете) поменять $array_a и  $array_b  местами

Comment: задумка вроде в верном направлении, но вот только понедельник A-массива затерялся.
`Array
(
    [Понедельник, 19 Ноября] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [-1] =>aaa
                )

        )

    [Вторник, 20 Ноября] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => bbb
                    [1] => ccc`. И тут немного не так...

Answer (score 0):

Пришлось сделать шаг в сторону и создать вспомогательные переменные. Сначала нужно сделать `$rusWeek = array_keys(A-arr)`, так видно порядковый номер дня недели. Обнуляем ключи у А-массива: `$a = array_values(A-arr)`. Соответственно, численные ключи В-массива будут равны `array_search($date, $rusWeek)`. Потом делаем `foreach`. `$result[$key] = $b[$key + 1] + $a[$key]`. Здесь все еще ключи числовые. Теперь чтоб ключи стали снова датами делаем `array_combine($rusWeek, $result)` и все!